# How to change application.yml file's property value in runtime of application

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties, reactive-feign-client

I have a scenario where I have to update value of a property in runtime only.
There is a restAPI endpoint which I'm calling in my springBoot Application through FeignClient. This restAPI URL gets changed frequently, hence I want a solution so that whenever this restAPI endpoint get changed, there should no need to Stop my application, build it and deploy it again.
The Approach I was trying is to update restAPI endpoint in application.yml file so that I can easily use it in @FeignCLient.
I tried to update property's value through actuator but it's not working.
Other Suggestion are highly appreciated.

1. Whenever I want I can update application.yml file's property so that I can use updated property in my application.
2. I tried with actuator endpoint to update property value failed to achieve the same.
3. Keep All other properties in application server's app.prop file only and create a application.prop file in gitHub repo store restAPI endpoint in github repo's app.prop file and import that properties in SpringBoot application.

Comment: Properties are meant to be static. If you want to modify something, use a Bean in code and external methods to update the values

Comment: Can you please show your code you've wrote for the Actuator attempt?

Comment: Agree to @OneCricketeer, properties are meant to be static and will be loaded at application run. Did you consider storing it in the Database and fetching the url from there? though not an ideal solution

Answer (score 0):

You should make the endpoint a dynamic property in application.properties file and externalize it to github or any other secure and remote location that can be accessible by your application using a config server. That is create a config server application and make your application a config client. This way if the endpoint changes, update your externalized property in github ( if you are using github as remote location) without redeploying your springboot application

Comment: Thanks !
But we don't have any config server this is monolithic application.

Comment: @SAMADHANSHEJUL Monolith doesn't matter. https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config